# Oracle SOA 12c Installation in windows 7 64 bit- Issues

Tags: oracle, soa, oracle12c, bpel

while i am running

java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar

I am executing this command from where my JDK is installed.

Error Message : This installer must be executed using java development  kit (JDK)

but  C;/program filed /jre is not a valid JDK.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install jdk8. Set JAVA_HOME to the installed jdk8. Navigate to %JAVA_HOME\bin. 
Run java -jar complete_path_of_dir\fmw_12.1.3.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c (12.1.3) requires a minimum of JDK 7.0 Update 55 or later. If you have an older version please update the JDK. 
Let’s say your JDK is installed in:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_xx
```

Search for cmd.exe in the Start menu. Right-click the cmd.exe and select Run as Administrator. In the prompt run the following command to set the JAVA_HOME:

```
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_xx"
```

Using the command prompt, navigate to the directory where you unzipped the jar files.
Launch the installation wizard with the appropriate command.

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar
```

For details about the installation refer to the official oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS209)

Comment: this is what i did ... but why is it not able to find the JAVA_HOME and goes to the jre folder instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you're unpacking a jar file which contains another jar file? Firstly, unzip the jar file and then execute the contained jar file.

Comment: sorry.. the addition .jar was typo .. edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

open your command prompt in admininstrative mode and change your directory to the *bin* directory of jdk(must be this path- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin).
Now from this directory, install the soa installer(.jar file) by giving its complete path. In my case, I had my soa installer in *E:* drive, so my command was like this:-

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>java -jar E:\fmw_12.2.1.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

in a simple way go to jdk bin folder and execute the following, shoot this command from my jdk\bin location:-
C:/Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>java -jar d:\fmw_12.2.1.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar

note: make sure you logged in as a admin user

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue when installing oracle fusion middleware, but i resolved it by following steps:

1. Open command prompt by right clicking 'Run as administrator'.
2. Install the latest JDK version.
3. Change the directory where your weblogic's .jar file is present like

   ```
    cd C:\Users\Ashwini_SP\Documents\Softwares\Jdeveloper_OSB\fmw_12.2.1.2.0_soaqs_Disk1_1of2
   ```
4. now select the jdk path and install it

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_soa_quickstart.jar
   ```